# How do I add a hyperlink to a cell in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlinks

In Excel, I can easily add a hyperlink to a cell by choosing the corresponding toolbar button. How do I do the same thing in a Google Doc spreadsheet?

I don't see any corresponding toolbar button or menu item. I'm using a Google Apps, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is the `HYPERLINK` function in the format of =HYPERLINK(*URL*; *TEXT TO DISPLAY*)

e.g.

```
=HYPERLINK("www.google.co.uk"; "Google")
```

Do not forget there is semicolon used between the actual link from the text.

Answer (score 3):

1. Click the *Insert link* icon in the toolbar:
   [image: toolbar screenshot]
   or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (or) right-click the cell and
   select *Insert link*.
2. Enter the text and link in the popup box and click *Apply*.
3. Hyperlink will be added to the text.

Note that this is for the [*new* Google Spreadsheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3541068?hl=en). If you're editing an older spreadsheet, these intstructions do not apply.

Click [Hyperlink Options](https://www.shorttutorials.com/google-docs-spreadsheet/insert-hyperlink.html) to know more about editing and deleting links.