# How do I link text to a URL in a Google Docs spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, links

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add a hyperlink to a cell in Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10389/how-do-i-add-a-hyperlink-to-a-cell-in-google-spreadsheets)

When I paste a URL into a cell in a Google Docs spreadsheet, it turns into a nice blue, underlined hyperlink. It also gives me the option to remove the hyperlink without clearing the cell:

[image]

Is there a way to hyperlink arbitrary text to a URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enter the hyperlink formula for it to convert said custom text to an external link of your choice.

```
=hyperlink("www.example.com";"attack of the green honda civic")
```

From: [Entering links - Google Docs help](http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=44660&hl=en).

Answer (score 2):

Google Docs automatically recognises text that should be a hyperlink.

I am guessing that you have removed a hyperlink using the method you describe (clicking `Remove`).  To add it back in you just need to right-click the cell and click `Show Hyperlinks`

[image: Google Docs - Show hyperlinks]